# How do I use sqlite with cordova while testing in a normal desktop browser?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, sqlite, cordova

While developing my Cordova hybrid application, I have grown very accustomed to testing my application in a regular desktop browser, and this has worked out very well so far.

Now I'd like to add sqlite functionality to my application. I see that there is a plugin for cordova, but I am curious, how can I write a fallback so that if cordova is not being used, I can use sqlite naturally without using the cordova plugin? Ideally, I'd like it to be abstracted so that the native sqlite object behaves exactly like the plugin, so I can do all of my testing in a regular browser to minimize the number of times I have to install my app to an actual device - the build time for android is very long, so I'd like to avoid it as much as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: First: Why don't you try emulator? second: build time is not that much! it took nearly 20-40 seconds. third: you can try ripple emulator. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc I haven't used it. But heard that you could actually run it in browser to test phonegap apps.

Comment: You can use WebSQL on desktop browser. The interface(API) is the same whether you use it in cordova or desktop browser. The underlying database used can be SQLite, but it depends on the browser. Check this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage) for WebSQL support among desktop browsers.

Comment: Great question - I see no one has provided an answer. Did you get anywhere on your own?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple wrapper which uses WebSQL for the browser and SQLite for the device. Just use different Database object. WebSQL and SQLite API is close to identical. You only need different initialization for browser and device.

Here is my example code(ES6):

```
var runiOS = false;
var DB;

// Check browser or device

var onDeviceReady = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {    
    if (document.URL.match(/^https?:/i)) {
        console.log("Running in a browser...");
        resolve();
    } else {
        console.log("Running in an app...");
        runiOS = true;
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", resolve, false);
    }
});

// Run application
onDeviceReady.then(function() {
    //  Init WebSQL on browser or SQLite on device
    if (runiOS) {
        DB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'my.db', location: 'default' }, function (db) {}, function (error) { console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error)); });          
        console.log('DB: SQLite');
    }
    else {
        DB = window.openDatabase('my', "0.1", "My list", 200000);    
        console.log('DB: WebSQL');
    }

    // ...

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DemoTable (name, score)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Alice', 101]);
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Betty', 202]);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
    }, function() {
        console.log('Populated database OK');
    });


    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT count(*) AS mycount FROM DemoTable', [], function(tx, rs) {
            console.log('Record count (expected to be 2): ' + rs.rows.item(0).mycount);
        }, function(tx, error) {
            console.log('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Sorry guys) I spent a lot of time to find solution how to test SQLite in the browser. And if I found a similar answer for me this would be enough. But I don't have enough time and I don't speak English well to give more detailed answer :) I hope this also can be useful for someone...

Comment: @ДмитрийВасильев I have existing database file, how can I import that file and then test into the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that works for me based on the answer of Дмитрий Васильев

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android)/)) {
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'mydb.db', location: 'default' }, function (db) {}, function (error) { console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error)); });          
    console.log('DB: SQLite');

}else {

    db = window.openDatabase('mydb', "0.1", "mydb description", 200000);    
    console.log('DB: WebSQL');
}
```

What happen here is that if the Android device is detected, the db object will switch to SQLITE or else if it is the browser, it will use WebSql.

To detect more devices you could use this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'mydb.db', location: 'default' }, function (db) {}, function (error) { console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error)); });          
    console.log('DB: SQLite');

}else {

    db = window.openDatabase('mydb', "0.1", "mydb description", 200000);    
    console.log('DB: WebSQL');
}
```

All you have to do is then run your code as normal and the db object will use the right database type.

Comment: why not just use plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device and then use ```device.platform``` for platform detection instead of the ```navigator.userAgent```